# VMWare Workstation VM Requires Boot From Firmware

Tags: boot, grub, uefi, vmware-workstation, efi

I have a VMWare Workstation virtual machine that seems to only boot into Ubuntu / Grub when you do a boot from firmware.

If I start the VM normal (not booting to firmware first), it will boot into a Grub prompt (recovery?).

[image: Grub Prompt]

If I use the boot menu and select the EFI boot option (Ubuntu) or I choose "boot normally", it will boot to the grub screen that boots the OS.

[image: Boot Menu]

[image: Grub Boot Menu]

I am using EFI boot. Here is the EFI boot setting.

[image: EFI Settings]

What am I doing wrong? I have tried installing boot-repair on the Ubuntu os and it says it is successful. I have also tried removing all boot options, manually adding boot options (I have tried nearly every .efi option under \EFI, and I have also tried letting boot-repair add the EFI option. Of course, I can boot into the OS using the boot menu but I would like to not do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very similar problem is detailed in the post
[GRUB starts in command line after reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot),
where Grub booted to the Rescue console.

Check first if the boot information in the UEFI/BIOS looks garbled,
and remove unknown partitions and reset the boot order.

A highly upvoted answer treated the case where Grub cannot find the root partition
that contains the startup data and have shown how to reset it:

- In the console, list all available devices using the command `ls`
- For each device, list its partition by commands such as `ls (hd0,1)/`
  and `ls (hd0,2)/` until you find one that looks like
  `(hd0,1)/boot/grub` or `(hd0,1)/grub`,
  or for EFI `(hd0,1)/efi/boot/grub` or `(hd0,1)/efi/grub`
- Set the boot parameters using the correct numbers:

  ```
    set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
    set root=(hd0,1)
    insmod linux
    insmod normal
    normal
  ```
- The computer should now boot correctly
- To complete the Grub information, start a terminal and enter the command
  `sudo update-grub`.

If this doesn't help, boot Linux through the
[Super Grub2 disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)
and reinstall `grub-efi` as follows :

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=debian --recheck --debug /dev/sda
update-grub
```

Comment: Hum... While this didn't work for me, it seems to be the best answer (only answer at the time of this comment) and you found something that I couldn't find when I searched. It did give me some ideas but in the end, I'm just going to redo my install since I didn't get very far in it.